# How to to export both the class and superclass in Node.js using module.exports and require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

This may be obvious, but I do not understand how to use `module.export` to export both the subclass and superclass. I'm currently getting the error `ReferenceError: not defined`. Here's the an example subclass `Dalmatian` in `/js/dalmatian.js`:

```
class Dalmatian extends Dog{
  constructor(){
       super();
      /// stuff
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Dalmatian : Dalmatian
}
```

If I then export this class in another `*.js` file, I run into problems:

```
require('../js/dog.js');   // this works
require('../js/dalmatian.js');   // this fails

ReferenceError: Dog is not defined
```

I don't understand. The super constructor is used within Dalmatian, i.e. `super();`.

How do I export the base class (which here is `Dog`) so I don't get this error?

Comment: you need to import the base Dog class from its module in the Dalmation before using it. Once exported, the modules can't see each other's methods/classes

Comment: @AbidHasan Sorry, I don't follow. Could you make this more concrete with code? I'm still a beginner with Node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `require` the parent class in your child class declaration. Also `export` the parent form subclass `export` clause.

You can then use both `Dog` and `Dalmatian` from your script that `requires('./dalmatian')` child class.

Here's a working example:

**dog.js**

```
class Dog{
    constructor(){
      console.log('dog');
  }
}

module.exports = Dog;
```

**dalmatian.js** (note how we export both)

```
const Dog = require('./dog');

class Dalmatian extends Dog{
    constructor(){
        super();
      console.log('dalmatian');
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Dalmatian : Dalmatian, //export this class
  Dog: Dog // and export parent class too!
}
```

**test.js**

```
const Dalmatian = require('./dalmatian').Dalmatian;
const Dog = require('./dalmatian').Dog; //---> Notice this
//const Dog = require('./dog'); ---> works too, but above is clearer and cleaner

new Dalmatian();
new Dog();
```

Output:

```
➔ node test.js
dog
dalmatian
dog
```

Comment: Could you explain why `const Dog = require('./dog');` exists in `dalmatian.js`? Currently, it looks like the Node.js application I'm using doesn't have this.

Comment: If you reference `Dog` in Dalmatian (which you do by saying `class Dalmatian extends Dog`), then you need to define Dog. That is why you have to import it

Comment: @ShanZhengYang is correct.  That's because. requires are executed in sequence. First one is dalmatian.js, which uses "Dog". So now node needs to know that before you use it. So you just need to require it in "dalmatian.js" before you use it. Makes sense?

Comment: @Shaunak This makes sense; I understand now why there was an error. I think you meant to reference Abid Hasan in the above comment.

Comment: I did actually :)

Answer (score 2):

`Dog` is not defined in the module containing `Dalmation`, because modules don't have access to each other's variables.

Your **Dalmation** module should look something like this:

```
var parentClass = require('./Dog.js')

class Dalmatian extends parentClass.Dog {
    constructor(){
      super();
      console.log('starting dalmation')
    }
}

module.exports = {
  Dalmatian: Dalmatian
}
```

Also, note the super() should be called **in** the constructor method, not before it.

Comment: "Also, note the super() should be called in the constructor method, not before it.". Apologies, this was a typo above. Thank you